# How in d3.js pass current selection to .each() callback?

Tags: d3.js

I have array of data and if I want to render this data as text I will use the next code

```
footer_item = svg_selection.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'footer_data')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')

footer_item.append('text')
  .text((d) => d)
  ...
```

What if instead of text I want to draw some shape. I can use this approach

```
footer_item
  .each((d) => {
    // draw some shape
    // don't know how to refer to footer_pointer
     draw_my_shape(footer_item_pointer, d.x, d.y);
  })

function draw_my_shape(footer_item_pointer, x, y){

    footer_item_pointer
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', x)
      .attr('cy', y)
      ... 
}
```

The only problem with this approach I will lose pointer to `footer_item`. I need pointer to `footer_item` to draw my shape inside `g` element.

Is it possible to send `footer_item` pointer with `.each()` function to my draw callback?

Can I use `.call()` function for that? I tried but then `d` variable will be contain full selection and full data. And I will come again to where I started.

Comment: Why do you think you were losing your reference? Given the code you provided I can see no evidence backing this assumption.

Comment: I updated my question. Can you look at the question again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to access `footer_item` inside of the `each` function. You can do this by *not* using an arrow function, and using the scope value of `this` in the function:

```
footer_item.each(function(d, i) {
        //"this" refers to the <g> html element that footer_item points to
        var foo = d3.select(this);
     });
```

You can then draw some more shapes on top of that selection:

```
foo.append('circle').attr(...
foo.append('rect').attr(...
```

Comment: you can still access `this` in an arrow function `(d, i, nodes)=>{...}` with `nodes[i]`. see https://github.com/d3/d3-selection